# Can't render chart in RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, rdlc

I'm using RDLC file to render a report (without SQL Server Reporting Services) and return it from my controller as a file. This is part of my MVC web application.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Report1.rdlc");
        var reportData = new List<MonthlyData> {
            new MonthlyData {RecordNo=1, Tid="123456", Active=10, Inactive=1}
        };
        ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", reportData);
        report.DataSources.Add(rd);
        string reportType = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;


        string deviceInfo =

            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "  <OutputFormat>" + "PDF" + "</OutputFormat>" +
            //"  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
            //"  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
            //"  <MagroupinTop>0.5in</MagroupinTop>" +
            //"  <MagroupinLeft>1in</MagroupinLeft>" +
            //"  <MagroupinRight>1in</MagroupinRight>" +
            //"  <MagroupinBottom>0.5in</MagroupinBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = report.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
    }
```

This is the result:

[table example in rdlc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHwrw.png)

Everything works like a charm until I decide to add a chart.

[rdlc file with chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/621XH.png)

Now when I render it I get two exceptions:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: „An error occurred during local report processing.”

DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'C:\Users\agutowski\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\rdlcMvc\rdlcMvc\Reports\Report1.rdlc' is invalid.
```

and

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: „An error occurred during local report processing.”

ReportProcessingException: The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.
```

**I already tried different versions of Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.**

Comment: Please include contents of the reporting target file located in `\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version]\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets`. I think it should contain `ReportViewer` assembly like this: `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=[version], Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.

Comment: Under `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft` there is no VisualStudio folder. I should add that I'm not working on admin account.

Comment: Have you using Chinese localization for `ReportViewer`? I think a workaround is possible by removing Chinese localization DLLs from the deployment package (exclude from publish). Try excluding all paths started with `zh-*` in the path.

Comment: @ Tetsuya Yamamoto What Chinese localization? No Idea what you mean.

Comment: The latest ReportViewer DLL reportedly has certain problem with DLL localization files for Chinese languages, try opening `Project Properties` => `Publish` => `Application Files` and set `Exclude` for ReportViewer DLL paths started with `zh` string (this tip may also apply for ASP.NET: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddff5e7f-2d77-4b64-b66f-9ef3aed041c7/invalid-report-definition-exception-when-creating-report-using-visual-studio-2017?forum=winforms).

Comment: I don't have such tab as `Publish` under my project properties. Only this [link](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/BlogFileStorage/blogs_msdn/webdevtools/WindowsLiveWriter/WebDeploymentExcludingFiles_10512/ItemsToDeploy_2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` NuGet packages instead of `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`.

Comment: I need the same but there is the same issue. I can see the text but not images or Charts.